# docker start not working as expected

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-container

I have simple ubuntu image

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04
RUN mkdir /home/work
WORKDIR /home/work
CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

After running commands

```
docker-compose build
docker-compose up -d
```

I want to "enter" created container

I run

```
docker start -ia ubuntu_container
```

And thats results to nothing. No output, no entering container.

So I remove container

```
docker rm ubuntu_container
```

And recreate it with a command

```
docker create -t -i --name ubuntu_container ubuntu /bin/bash
```

And after this same start command

```
 docker start -ia ubuntu_container
```

Results in

```
root@d823966eface:/home/work#
```

Why does it behave like that?
I dont wanna removing and creating over new container after building / composing. What I should do to start automatically created container properly?

Comment: Try `docker exec`, see https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/#extended-description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came to this resolution.
I set **tty:true** in docker-compose.yml

```
ubuntu:
  tty: true
```

So docker container with Ubuntu does not exit with code 0 immediately after starting and keeps running.

So I dont need to

```
docker start -ia ubuntu_container
```

I do this to enter started container.

```
docker exec -it dockerlemp_ubuntu_1 /bin/bash
```

Answer (score 0):

When you run docker-compose up with the -d switch, it runs the container in detached mode. After running with -d use:

```
docker attach ubuntu_container
```

to access the shell.